# Interface and declare combinations in typescript

Tags: typescript

When you look through the [collections typings file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts) you frequently see the pattern:

```
interface Set<T> {
    add(value: T): this;
    clear(): void;
    delete(value: T): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, value2: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    has(value: T): boolean;
    readonly size: number;
}

interface SetConstructor {
    new (): Set<any>;
    new <T>(values?: T[]): Set<T>;
    readonly prototype: Set<any>;
}
declare var Set: SetConstructor;
```

that is:

- an interface for a collection type
- a constructor interface
- and a variable with `declare`

I cannot really make sense of that. Can someone please answer some questions?

1. The purpose of `Set<T>` is clear, but where is the actual implementation? When I call `new Set()` what do I actually create? In other languages I cannot instantiate an interface (it's not meant to be instantiated), but only a class which implements the interface.
2. What's the purpose of that set constructor interface? It's not a class, so it doesn't represent executable code.
3. The `declare var` part is the most confusing thing here:

   - `declare` is meant to introduce a type that is implemented somewhere else. How can it be used for a variable? And, isn't the `import` (or `require`) supposed to get in code which is implemented elsewhere?
   - It defines a variable with the same name as the Set interface. Why doesn't that conflict with each other?
   - It "combines" the 2 interfaces somehow (`Set` for the name, `SetConstructor` for the type) that's making me shake my head. What is that for actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)
All of the different lib files describe native objects and classes that are already present in the environment in which you will run the script (browser/node).
That's why you don't see the implementation for those interfaces.

(2)
All of the interfaces post-fixed with `Constructor` represent the static part of the classes along with the constructors.

Both of those (`Set` and `SetConstructor`) together represent the `Set` class which has a native implementation.
The `Set` interface describes the instances while `SetConstructor` represents the class.

The different constructor methods (described in `SetConstructor`) return `Set`, so while you don't instantiate the `Set` interface you do get an instance of it.

All of the native types are already part of the environment, there's no need to import `string`, `Set`, `Map`, `Promise`, etc.
And by declaring them (using the `declare` keyword) you're telling the compiler that the variable is there at runtime.

(3)
You need to differentiate between values and types.
For example:

```
type MyPoint = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
const MyPoint: MyPoint = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}
```

Here `MyPoint` is both a type (the interface) and a value (the const variable) and they both have the same name, and there's no conflict between the two because you never use a name as both a variable and a type.
Notice that classes for example are both a type and a value so you cannot re-use a class name.

It doesn't "combine" the two interfaces, what happens is:
There's a variable called `Set` and it's type is `SetConstructor`.
When you are creating a new instance (`new Set()`) you are invoking one of the methods in this `Set` variable and the return value is of type `Set` (the interface).

Hope this clears this out.

---

#### Edit

You should look at the `Set` variable as something like:

```
const MyClass = class {
    constructor(public x: string) {}
}
```

The `Set` interface in this case is:

```
interface MyClass {
    x: string;
}
```

And the `SetConstructor`:

```
interface MyClassConstructor {
    new (str: string): MyClass;
    readonly prototype: MyClass;
}
```

The only difference is that the implementation of `Set` is native.

Comment: So, there is magic going on behind the scenes where my `new Set()` call is converted to `Set.new()` (where the variable `Set` comes into play)?

Comment: No, there's no magic. Check my revised answer, hopefully it will explain this part. If not, let me know and we'll try again :)

Comment: Sorry, but your edit doesn't explain anything, only repeating the original code with new names ;-) To me it's not clear how the `SetConstructor` comes into play here. When I call `new Set()` I neither instantiate an interface nor a variable, but a class. But there is no `Set` class here at all.

Comment: The actual implementation isn't in the files, it's a native class that your browser implements (If you do: `console.log(Set)` you'll get: `function Set() { [native code] }`). The ambient declarations that you're asking about are just declerations that explain to the compiler what's already implemented. While the `Set` interface describes the **instances** of a Set, it cannot describe the constructors (and static properties) because an instance doesn't have a constructor. That's where the `SetConstructor` comes in, it represents the class.